# Should I call the send function from WinAPI in a loop

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, winapi, network-programming

Should I call the `send` function from WinAPI (https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms740149(v=vs.85).aspx) in a loop to guarantee that all data has been sent (like the similar `send` function from Python standard library) or does it work like the `sendall` function?

Comment: Did you read this part of the documentation? ***Return value** If no error occurs, send returns the total number of bytes sent, which can be less than the number requested to be sent in the len parameter. Otherwise, a value of SOCKET_ERROR is returned, and a specific error code can be retrieved by calling WSAGetLastError.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python and the Winsock API both implement the BSD socket api, so the `send` function works pretty much identically. So no, it is not a convenient `sendall` and far FAR too much code assumes it is.

You could write a simple `sendall` function on windows by looping on send until all the bytes have been successfully sent, but this is a bad idea in GUI applications as it will prevent the application from responding to the user, and in more complex console applications it might prevent other sockets communicating.

If either of these is a concern, you should investigate `WSAAsyncSelect` for GUI applications, where your window proc will receive window messages each time the socket is ready to be read or written to, or `select` which allows a console program / non gui worker thread to loop on a collection of up to 32 sockets (windows limitation) to test which ones are readable or writable.